# How can I send android push notifications through a QR Code?

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I am developing an android application and using Zxing QR Code generator. I am wondering if the result of a QR Code can be an android push notification. If so, how can that be done? Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "result of a QR Code can be an android push notification."

Comment: So whenever I scan a created QR Code on my app I want a push notification to appear on my phone.  Just like this: https://www.google.com/search?q=push+notifications+android&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwja-Z668dvVAhWGQyYKHctpAxgQ_AUICygC&biw=1269&bih=708#imgrc=qtpD89MFfV1GcM:

I want to programmatically do that in Android Studio. I know the result of a QR Code can be text or url's but just wondering if they can also be push notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is to do a local notification as soon as a QR code is scanned and show the content of the scan result as a notification. Push notifications on the other hand are sent from server. Hence both are different

You can do Local notifications using `NotificationCompat.Builder`

A simple way to generate a notification is  -

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("My notification")
    .setContentText("Hello World!");

// Sets an ID for the notification
int mNotificationId = 001;
// Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Builds the notification and issues it.
mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

You can also learn about generating different types of notifications from the links below -

[Link 1](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/easy-way-to-send-local-notification-to-user-in-android)

[Link 2](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html)

Comment: Understood! In my case I want the scan result to be a push notification. I will look into those links you provided and I will try it. Thank you!

Comment: I got it to work but I only get the notifications if I scan the QR Code with the scanner integrated in my app. It is not working if I scan it with a third party QR Code scanner such as the one integrated on the android phone.

Comment: Yeah because that part is not in your control as the third parties are not implemented in that manner and they would only show the scan content on screen. You won't be able to do what you want if third party is used to scan the code.

Comment: Okay. Got it! I will work on what you provided then! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a database like your QR code or ID in front FCM token when QR code Scan that time simultaneously make one service call if the record exists then send notification to the specific device.